# Saving static values of object

Tags: android, static

When adding an object to a Bundle in order to save it in onSaveInstance does it save the state of all the static variables or will then be reset when I reload using onRestoreInstance?

As an extension of the question, is it possible to save a non-instantiated class. In other words just the statics?
I am using it for a card game and since I will only ever have one deck of cards it seems silly to have to instantiate it when I can use all statics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an OO perspective, it would make more sense to model your deck of cards on the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern rather than making it static. Then you can save that object in the Bundle and restore it without having to worry about the static issue. If you care about such things, this method also makes for 'better' object oriented programming.

Comment: Funnily enough, when I mentioned it to my son he said the same thing and he is still a student (last year)!